# Logic behind this sequence is built but a problem is occurring?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I have to print `8` terms of the sequence as

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 22, 26, 38, ....
```

I have completed my logic till `16` that every new term is the previous term multiplied by `2`. And after `16` the logic is that we divide that part into two as

```
26 = 22 + (2 * 2)
```

Till now what I have done is

```
int x = 1, num, num1, n = 1;
while (n <= 10)
{
   while (n <= 4)
   {
      if (n == 1)
      {
         cout << x << ", ";
      }
      num = x % 10;
      num1 = num % 10;
      x = x * 2;
      cout << x << ", ";
      n++;
   }
   if (x == 16)
   {
      num = x % 10;
      num1 = num % 10;
      x = x + (num * num1) - 30;
      cout << x << ", ";
   }
   else
   {
      num = x % 10;
      num1 = num % 10;
      x = x + (num * num1);
      cout << x << ", ";
   }
   n++;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't post text as image.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Apparently we just add the product of all digits to current number. That works fine for 1, 2, 4, 8 as well, so no need to have any special handling. However, apparently we need to ignore zeros, otherwise we wouldn't change after 102 any more...

Comment: Hmm i am not getting the error check my ooutput shown in image for this code

Comment: I have to print 10 terms of the sequence as 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 22, 26, 38, 62, 74, 102, 104. Its the question

Comment: *'I have to print 10 terms'* – always 10? No modification? Probably not in the sense of the task, but `std::cout << "1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 22, 26, 38, 62, 74" << std::endl;` would do that, too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we just add the product of all digits to current number. That works fine for 1, 2, 4, 8 as well (e. g. `4 = 2 + (2)`), so no need to have any special handling. However, apparently we need to ignore zeros, otherwise we wouldn't change after 102 any more...

So we can simplify the altorithm quite a bit:

```
unsigned int number = 1; // start value
std::cout << number; // OK, would require special handling for n == 0...

while(n--) // you could ask the user to input n or just set it to 10
           // (I consider this variant a bit more elegant)
{
    unsigned int product = 1;
    unsigned int tmp = number;
    // now iterate as long as you have more digits!
    while(tmp)
    {
        unsigned int modulo = tmp % 10;
        tmp /= 10;
        // neat little trick: if modulo != 0, comparison is false, which is
        // converted to 0, which is neutral for OR operation; otherwise, we
        // get 0 | 1, which is neutral for multiplication... 
        product *= modulo | (modulo == 0);
    }
    number += product;
    std::cout << ", " << number;
}
```

This would work fine even for fare more numbers than just the first ten ones (until overflow of either the product or the sum occurs...).